# C++ managed array size

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, argument-passing

I have this

```
function(array<Object^>^ a)
```

How do I know the length of this array? Like C++, the size has to come with the function?

Thanks,

Comment: `int i = a->Length;` Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that All of you classes are from the .net library so in the general case you can allays looks at the generic .net documentation. Here is the array class [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Function in your case:

```
function(array<Object^>^ a) {
    auto len = a->Length
}
```